# dc.js legend is not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, dc.js

I have a pie chart that I am displaying within a quadrant `<div>` box. The pie chart displays fine and when I inspect the element on the page I can see the legend but it has a width and height of 0. I've tried using `.dc-legend svg { width: 100px; height: 100px; }` to force it to  be a certain size but it remains 0x0

```
<div class="quadrant_right">
<div id="CityCharttext"><span>Dummy graph</span></div>
    <div id="city-chart"></div>
</div>
<script>
    function InitPieChart(string){
        // cities.forEach(function(city){
           cities.forEach(function(city){
            DataForPieGraph.push({Name:city,data:(test.SumHelper(Projectsall, city, string))});
           })
    var ndx           = crossfilter(DataForPieGraph),
    nameDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.Name;}),
    spendPerName = nameDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.data;});

          CityChart
           .width(200).height(176)
            .dimension(nameDim)
            .group(spendPerName)
            .innerRadius(30)
             .colors(['#39393B', '#58585B', '#858688', '#A7A9AB','#E8EBF1','#C4D6ED','#64BBE3','#049FD9','#097DBC','#004BAF'])
            .label(function(d) { return d.data.value})
            .legend(dc.legend().x(0).y(0).itemHeight(13).gap(5));
            CityChart.render()

    }
</script>
```

I left out a bunch of other stuff to focus my topic on this question and to not clutter up the code, but I may have left something out.

**Thanks in advance!!**

**CSS**

```
            #city-chart svg { width: 350px; }
    #city-chart{
      width:350px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px -1px;
       position:relative;
     float:left;
   }
```

Comment: Please verify that you are using the 2.0 betas - this feature is not available in 1.7.*. More info: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1159

Comment: how would I update using node? `$ npm update dc.js` didn't fix it.

Comment: In your package.json, depend on `"dc": "~2.0.0-beta"`

Comment: Cool, that was my problem. It works perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the CSS for #city-chart too.

Comment: I updated my question with what I am setting the CSS too. doesnt seem to change anything....